# How to get a max number using Breezejs query or is it doable?

Tags: breeze

While creating a new record using BreezeJs, I want to specify a new number. For example, creating an employee contact, I want to automatically specify the sequence, like 1, 2 ,3 etc.

```
NextSequence = Max(Sequence) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I did following -

```
getLastMemberCode()
  {
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
      .from('TblMembersMaster')
      .select('MembersCode')
      .orderByDesc('MembersCode')
      .take(1)
      .inlineCount();

    return createEntityManager()
      .then(em => em.executeQuery(query))
      .then(queryResult => {
        return queryResult.results[0].MembersCode
      });
  }
```

And added 1 to the result.